# problems using a dblclick event on a created layer with leaflet js("cannot read property 'on' of undefined")

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

im sorry if this is a newbie problem. I was also searching inside the forum but did not find something like my issue.

I'm using leaflet(mapbox js) and I have a global variable  that is used inside a function called `inicializarMapa()`. Then the function is called and finally I use a `layerName.on('dbclick',function(){ Do something})`. But console fires a message that says `"cannot read property 'on'  of undefined"`.

The markers appears in my map. But I dont know why I cannot do the dblclick event.

I hope you can help me finding why the variable is going `undefined`, thank you very much for your time :).

```
var myLayer;
function inicializarMapa(){

$.ajax({                                      
      url: 'consulta4.php',                  
      data:{
            },                        
      method: 'POST',                               
      dataType:'json',                
      success: function(data)          
      {   
        for(var i in data)
        {

           var geojson = [{
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
              "type": "Point",
              "coordinates": [data[i].longitude,data[i].latitude]
                        },

                "properties": {
                "title": "Emergencia: "+data[i].priority,
                "id":data[i].id_emergency,
                //"descripcion":"<button class='RE'>oisdjos</button>", Forma alternativa de añadir html   
                "icon": {
                "iconUrl": data[i].imagen,
                "iconSize": [50, 50], // size of the icon
                "iconAnchor": [25, 50], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
                "popupAnchor": [0, -25], // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
                "className": "dot"
                        }
                        }
                }];     //alert(data[i].longitude.valueOf());

                myLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().setGeoJSON(geojson).addTo(map);
                myLayer.on('click',function(e){
                   //console.log(e.layer.feature.properties.title);
                    map.panTo(e.layer.getLatLng());

                });
                myLayer.on('layeradd', function(e) {
                marcadorEMG[i]= e.layer;
                var feature = marcadorEMG[i].feature;
                marcadorEMG[i].setIcon(L.icon(feature.properties.icon));



                 /*var popupContent =  '<a target="_blank" class="popup" href="' + feature.properties.url + '">' +
                            '<img src="' + feature.properties.image + '" />' +
                            feature.properties.city +
                        '</a>';    */
                var popupContent='<div class="contenedor-min-principal"><div class="contenedor-info"><b>'+feature.properties.title+'</b><p>Id emergencia:'+feature.properties.id+'</p></div><div class="contenedor-btn"><button class="emg" value="'+data[i].id_emergency+'">Modificar</button><button class="reporte" value="'+data[i].id_emergency+'">Reporte</button><button class="asistida" value="'+data[i].id_emergency+'">Finalizar</button></div><div class="contenedor-emg"><form class="formamin-emg">Dirección:<input type="text" id="direccion-emg-min" maxlength="50">Prioridad<select id="prioridad-emg-min"></select>Tipo punto interés<select id="tipo-pto-interes-emg-min"></select><div class="btn-final-aceptar"><input type="submit" value="Aceptar"></div></form></div></div>';//IMPORTANTISIMO

                marcadorEMG[i].bindPopup(popupContent,{
                closeButton: true,
                   minWidth: 300,
                    maxwidth:300
                });

                contadorEmergencias++;
                });
                myLayer.setGeoJSON(geojson);
            contadorEMG=i;
          }  
      }
 });//Fin ajax emergencias
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////



}//fin inicializar mapa

inicializarMapa();
myLayer.on('dblclick',function(){alert("hi");});
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens because when you try to bind `dblclick` to your `myLayer`, `myLayer` doesn't contain the featureGroup yet because `inicializarMapa` is still running. You'll need to bind in your success callback function just like you did with the `addlayer` and `click` events.

EDIT after comment, this is your success method whichs gets executed after loading from `consulta4.php` has finished:

```
$.ajax({                                      
    url: 'consulta4.php',
    data: {},
    method: 'POST',
    dataType:'json',
    success: function (data) { // <- Start of your success method/function

    } // <- end of your success method/function
});
```

What you're doing now:

```
var myLayer;

$.ajax({                                      
    url: 'consulta4.php',
    data: {},
    method: 'POST',
    dataType:'json',
    success: function (data) { // <- Start of your success method/function
        myLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer();
    } // <- end of your success method/function
});

// This is called before the success method has finished, so calling
// 'on' will fail because it's a method of featureLayer, and myLayer
// doesn't hold a featureLayer yet
myLayer.on('dblclick, function () {...});
```

So you'll need to bind to the `dblclick` event in the `success` method, after you've defined the featureLayer on variable myLayer:

```
var myLayer;

$.ajax({                                      
    url: 'consulta4.php',
    data: {},
    method: 'POST',
    dataType:'json',
    success: function (data) { // <- Start of your success method/function
        myLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer();
        myLayer.on('dblclick, function () {...});
    } // <- end of your success method/function
});
```

Edit²: You could declare your featureLayer and attach the handler before your ajax call:

```
var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);

featureLayer.on('dblclick', function () {});

$.ajax({                                      
    url: 'consulta4.php',
    data: {},
    method: 'POST',
    dataType:'json',
    success: function (data) {
        featureLayer.setGeoJSON(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Im kind of newbie about ajax, but how can i bind my success callback function?. Ill appreciate if you tell me that for a further reading. :)

Comment: im asking because i want that function if `inicializar()` happens or not. in other words outside that function

Comment: Added some extra explanation in my answer. Good luck!

Comment: is there any chance to call it from outside  of the function? thx :)

Comment: Added another option to my answer.

Comment: the second solution lets me do some events but  the popup content is only attaching the last recovered data from the ajax. why is this happening?